# Page not found return false

Tags: uri

Im using a custom query to display some content. 
This query uses url arguments as MySQL variables.

Usually when I create a link with the variables the page does not exist and it returns a 404 error.

Is there a way of creating a page on certain urls to avoid getting an "page not found"?

EDIT:
To be more specific

The query is something like

```
SELECT * WHERE node.type = '.arg(0).' AND node_data_field_type.field_type = '.arg(1).'
```

The url intended would be: **example.com/exhibition/speacial_feature** or 
**example.com/program/speaker_series**

The link exhibition/speacial_feature or program/speaker_series are not found.

Comment: can you give some examples of the urls you are creating? this might help out in resolving your problem

Comment: Note that your query is, if really done like that, insecure and open for SQL-Injection. Use placeholders! (see db_query() documentation).

Comment: Ouch, no query placeholders, SQL args from querystring.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that example.com is a site running Drupal, what Drupal does when you try to access  example.com/exhibition/speacial_feature is:

- Verify exhibition/speacial_feature is a path alias
- Verify there is a menu that uses exhibition/speacial_feature as path
- Verify a module define a menu callback for exhibition/speacial_feature

If none of the conditions is verified, then Drupal returns a 404 error.

In your case, as you want to execute code when a path is entered, you need to create a module that defines a menu callback.

```
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['mymodule/%/%'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_abc_view',
    'page arguments' => array(1, 2),
  );

  return $items;
}

function mymodule_page_view($first, $second) {
  // Execute the query, and show the result.
}
```

The code for `hook_menu()` I shown is the minimum required; see [hook_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) for more information.

As also noted from Berdir, you don't concatenate input given from a user to obtain the query to execute, as that causes [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You need to use query parameters, which are supported in any Drupal version. Also, with [static queries](http://drupal.org/node/310072), the name of the database tables are surrounded by *{* and *}*.

Answer (score 0):

When a request is made to a Drupal site, it looks up in the menu router and the url table to see if that link exists. Since you are using a custom query, it will fail to recognize your new pattern. You can either create a normal node, a URL alias as per your requirements, and change the content in the node.tpl.php file.

Otherwise, you can create a menu. Say your custom URL is foobar/X, where X is varying.

```
 $items['foobar/%'] = array(
   'page callback' => 'foo_page',
   'page arguments' => array(1, 'foo'),
 );
```

Then, in the page callback, fetch the custom content and return it.

Comment: This is probably it, unfortunately I don't know how to apply or test it. Could you elaborate with more detail?

Excuse my ignorance but I don't know exactly what the callback function is or where to run it.